# Counting how many times each vowel appears

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I've written a little program to count how many times each vowel appears in a list, but it's not returning the correct count, and I can't see why:

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
vowelCounts = [aCount, eCount, iCount, oCount, uCount] = (0,0,0,0,0)
wordlist = ['big', 'cats', 'like', 'really']

for word in wordlist:
    for letter in word:
        if letter == 'a':
            aCount += 1
        if letter == 'e':
            eCount += 1
        if letter == 'i':
            iCount += 1
        if letter == 'o':
            oCount += 1
        if letter == 'u':
            uCount += 1
for vowel, count in zip(vowels, vowelCounts):
    print('"{0}" occurs {1} times.'.format(vowel, count))
```

The output is

```
"a" occurs 0 times.
"e" occurs 0 times.
"i" occurs 0 times.
"o" occurs 0 times.
"u" occurs 0 times.
```

However, if I type `aCount` in the Python shell, it gives me `2`, which is correct, so my code has indeed updated the aCount variable and stored it correctly. Why isn't it printing the correct output?

Comment: You assigned `vowelCounts` to a tuple of zeros. It is not in any way connected to the variables, and there is no way to do that. You'd be better off assigning to it after the loop.

Comment: Just use `collections.counter`.

Comment: Part of the puzzle: Consider `foo = bar = 0`. Its not surprising that `foo` and `bar` both equal zero. In `vowelCounts = [aCount, eCount, iCount, oCount, uCount] = (0,0,0,0,0)`, python assigned `(0,0,0,0,0)` to `[aCount, eCount, iCount, oCount, uCount]` using pythons [sequence unpacking]( https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) rules, and also assigned `(0,0,0,0,0)` to `vowelCounts`. If you print `vowelCounts` you'll notice its a tuple not a list.

Comment: Stylistic point. Don't use multiple assignment in this way: `a = b = (1, 2, 3)`. It's highly unreadable and leads to hard to track errors (if you don't know where to look) such as the one here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
vowelCounts = [aCount, eCount, iCount, oCount, uCount] = (0,0,0,0,0)
```

`vowelCounts` does not get updated if you start incrementing `aCount` later.

Setting `a = [b, c] = (0, 0)` is equivalent to `a = (0, 0)` and `[b, c] = (0, 0)`. The latter is equivalent to setting `b = 0` and `c = 0`.

Reorder your logic as below and it will work:

```
aCount, eCount, iCount, oCount, uCount = (0,0,0,0,0)

for word in wordlist:
    for letter in word:
        # logic 

vowelCounts = [aCount, eCount, iCount, oCount, uCount]

for vowel, count in zip(vowels, vowelCounts):
    print('"{0}" occurs {1} times.'.format(vowel, count))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use collections counter (which is the natural go-to function when counting things, it returns a dictionary):

```
from collections import Counter

vowels = list('aeiou')
wordlist = ['big', 'cats', 'like', 'really']

lettersum = Counter(''.join(wordlist))

print('\n'.join(['"{}" occurs {} time(s).'.format(i,lettersum.get(i,0)) for i in vowels]))
```

Returns:

```
"a" occurs 2 time(s).
"e" occurs 2 time(s).
"i" occurs 2 time(s).
"o" occurs 0 time(s).
"u" occurs 0 time(s).
```

lettersum:

```
Counter({'l': 3, 'a': 2, 'e': 2, 'i': 2, 'c': 1, 'b': 1, 
         'g': 1, 'k': 1, 's': 1, 'r': 1, 't': 1, 'y': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
wordlist = ['big', 'cats', 'like', 'really']
new_words = ''.join(wordlist)
new_counts = {i:sum(i == a for a in new_words) for i in vowels}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 2, 'e': 2, 'i': 2, 'o': 0, 'u': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @jpp said
simple datatypes like integers are returned by value not by reference 
so when you assign it to something and change that something it doesn't get affected

```
a = 10
b = a #b=a=10
b = 11 #b=11, a=10
print a, b
--> 10 11
```

I'd have made this a comment to his but I need reputation to do that :D

Comment: Not quite. The difference here is that `b` is being reassigned. Try `a = [10]`;b=a;b=[11]` and you'll see the same behavior even though a list most definitely not "returned by value".

Comment: but b=[11] is reassigning b to another list while if you do b[0]=11 now a=[11]

Comment: You did `b = 11` which is reassignment. The difference in python objects isn't whether they are passed by value or reference (they are all passed the same) but by whether they are mutable or immutable, or more fundamentally, what their "magic" methods do. In `b[0]=11` the mutable object's `list.__setitem__()` method was called, and it decided what to do. No reassignment of `b` itself was made.

Comment: seems like my c++ background's got the best of me again thank you for the clarification